# Can you help me get a date with this girl?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

There are 3 puzzles below. To reach the second puzzle, you have to solve the first. The image has hidden messages and keys.

I need you to help me get a date with this pretty girl in my uni. She prefers smart guys, so she placed the name and address of a restaurant on her blog. Can you help me identify the place?

**First puzzle:** I should meet her on a street. What is the name of the street?

The street name is inside of the picture.

> Link the phone number with info in the blog and you'll get the name of the street

[image]

**Second puzzle:** Also from the above image, you'll discover which store she will be in. After you found out which street she is on, you noticed in that there are 5 shops, and know that she is in one of them.

Which place is she in?

> Link the bio with the store type and you'll get the name of the store

**Beautiful Roses (store for roses)

Police Station

Stylish Haircuts for Men (hair salon)

Read Me (book store)

Macburger (restaurant)**

**Third puzzle:** After you solve the above puzzle, you'll have the below image that will lead you to her.
After you know where to meet her, you go inside and you ask for her. They tell you that the girl left and the location is inside of the envelope.

[image]

Comment: She said her age is 31/02/102? Also what is the main question here, is it her name, or the location inside the envelope?

Comment: @MarkN its a hidden message btw you asnwer for the third riddle was almost right

Comment: It seems redundant to solve the first two parts of the riddle if you continue the plot further for us assuming we have the answer. I would either suggest only asking the last part of the riddle, or split this up into 3 separate but connected questions. (Only asking the next stage after the prior is solved)

Comment: @MarkN well riddle1 doesnt need a plot..the phone is a hint to understand the location of the street

Comment: This puzzle isn't bad; I suspect the downvotes are because of the title, which some might find offensive. I'm reluctant to upvote (though of course I haven't downvoted) for the same reason. Maybe you should edit the title?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The street is probably

> "Canal Street" If you type the phone number in an old flip phone as a text message, 222-2-66-2-... translates to "canal str"

This is a guess, but..

> She's probably at the bookstore, because it says she likes to read.

I have no idea what's meant by the 3rd part with the envelope.

> I mean, maybe she's at a seafood restaurant, but she's a vegetarian. Does she eat fish? Maybe she's a pescetarian?

Random additional note:

> Her age (I'm assuming it was supposed to be birth date), '31/02/102' is also suspicious for a number of reasons. I'm pretty sure she's not almost 2000 years old, and February doesn't have 31 days. So that probably has something to do with something. Or maybe not. Who knows.

Comment: Ah, the fish logo is the logo of "Beach Side Seafood Restaurant", for whatever that's worth.

Comment: Yeap you are right about the riddels .. the age is the address off the sea fish restaurant

Comment: Thanks. I did a google image search and came up with this: http://bestbrandlogos.com/restaurant-logos/beachside-seafood-logo/ but wasn't sure exactly what to do with that information...

Answer (score 1):

The street could be:

> Sandy lane

The building could be:

> The police station (where she finds her phone) or the book store since she is a 'shopholic' and likes to read

Could she be at:

> The beach
>
>  He name is "C Fish" in the blog contact information (Fish live in the sea), and Sandy (Sand). When you put them together you get a beach. Also the picture has a fish on it.
>
> Plus with the image given it could be a **Beach Side Seafood Restaurant** (Thanks to Bailey M). Which might seem like an odd place for a vegitarian.

Comment: the are riddles 1 and 2 , can you guess what are they ?

Comment: Ah, the fish logo is the logo of "Beach Side Seafood Restaurant", for whatever that's worth.

Answer (score -1):

street name

> canal street

she is in

> book store

her name is

> sandy fish
>
> Canal street because of typing the phone number in your old mobile phone it says canal st
> Also as she likes to read book so she might wait in the book store and about the name sandy from blog's name

Comment: Why? Why? and Why?

Comment: canal street because of typing the phone number in your old mobile phone it says canal st also as she likes to read book so she might wait in the book store and about the name sandy from blog's name

Comment: A good answer includes the explanation in the answer... that is all i meant.